# Finding $M_{ij}$ from $J_{i} = -\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}M_{jk}$ of the Lorentz group

Tags: homework-and-exercises, angular-momentum, tensor-calculus

I cannot understand why if
$$J_{i} = -\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}M_{jk}$$
then 
$$M_{ij}= -\epsilon_{ijk}J_{k}.$$
Here $M_{ij}$ is the generator of the 4 dimensional Lorentz algebra (although I have only taken the rotations here so this is why I only have included latin indices ) and $J_i$ is the rotation around the i-th axis. Can you enlighten me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Contract both sides of the first equation with $e^{ijk}$. In three dimensions, we have the identity for the Levi-Civita, $$\epsilon_{ijk} \epsilon^{imn} = \delta_j^m \delta_k^n - \delta_j^n \delta_k^m.$$ Using the antisymmetry of the $M_{jk}$, you obtain the second equation.

Answer (score 1):

It's a well known identity that

$\epsilon_{ijk}\epsilon_{klm} = \delta_{il}\delta_{jm} - \delta_{im}\delta_{jl}$

Therefore, if

$$J_{i} = -\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{ijk}M_{jk}$$

then we have:

$$\begin{align}
\epsilon_{lmi}J_{i} &= -\frac{1}{2}\epsilon_{lmi}\epsilon_{ijk}M_{jk}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}\left(\delta_{lj}\delta_{mk}-\delta_{lk}\delta_{mj}\right)M_{jk}\\
&=-\frac{1}{2}M_{lm} + \frac{1}{2}M_{ml}\\
M_{[lm]} &= -\epsilon_{lmi}J_{i}
\end{align}$$

Comment: Oh right, I knew the identity I could not see that I had to use it though. Thanks